# Crear app con Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Trabajo con ionic 3.10, al momento de crear un proyecto me pide si deseo conectarme a Git y me pide credenciales correo y pass, al escoger la N de No me da un error ya que me pide credenciales.
[image: Ionic3]

Error
[image: IOnic3]

¿De que manera puedo escoger la opción N y no me salga error?

Saludos

Comment: Pedro! saludos!, porque no agregas una imagen con el mensaje o que tipo de error te muestra!, revisa [ask] hehe!

Comment: @Jorgesys Es que cuando agrego una imagen me dicen que no, que no es la manera, entonces ya no se ni como preguntar, jejeje.

Comment: @Jorgesys Actualizado el hilo.

Comment: que imágenes tan feas! es broma hehe!, considero que en este caso es bueno agregar esta información, de hecho tom ya agrego una respuesta. @PedroÁvila

Comment: @Jorgesys, jajaja.... que buena broma siguiendo lo de Tom me pide que debo estar dentro del directorio de Git. ¿Es una convención en Ionic 3 logear en Git?

Answer (score 1):

#### Esto funcionó para mí

*Ejecute estos dos comandos:*

```
 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "Your name"
```

Puede modificar la dirección de correo electrónico y el nombre de usuario en esos comandos

---

Editar
La particularidad de mi respuesta es que la explico más en detalles

Answer (score 0):

¿y registrando las credenciales de git aunque no se vayan a utilizar?

```
git config user.name "nombre"
git config user.email "email@email.com"
```

¿no dejaría continuar de esa forma?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta, ¿como soluciono ese problema?, si tengo cuenta en Git. ¿Es una convención logear a Git al crear el proyeto?

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git>git config user.email minimainor_austin@hotmail.com
fatal: not in a git directory @Tom

Comment: Fijate si podés registrarlas de forma global como indica la imagen, agregando "--global". Ejemplo: ->    git config --global user.name "nombre"

Comment: Cuando utilizas el comando start del Ionic CLI, automáticamente crea el proyecto Ionic como un repositorio GIT

Comment: Ya pude crear el proyecto, he creado una cuenta de ionic es eso lo que me pedía y al hacerlo me salió otro cosa sobre una key de ssh, pero bueno lo obvie y pude crear Hola Mundo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes deshabilitar que te pida las credenciales:

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```